# SimpleWebRTC with PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, webrtc

Is there any way to use SimpleWebRTC (from simplewebrtc.com) and Cordova?
Do you know if WebKit Safari supports it?

I am trying to:

1. Create a phonegap project
2. Include simplewebrtc js
3. Connect to a room

Answer (score 0):

Currently WebRTC is not supported in the browsers Safari and Internet Explorer. More on that:

- http://iswebrtcreadyyet.com/
- http://www.webrtc.org/
- http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream

Meaning SimpleWebRTC will not run on the Safari browser or in phonegap.
You can however use WebRTC with phonegap using OpenTok's services:

- http://www.tokbox.com/blog/opentok-now-on-phonegap/

(note: Works only on iOS)

Or you could try:

- https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc